# Retrieving a report from GoodData using Python?

Tags: python, gooddata

Is it possible to retrieve a report from GoodData using Python?

All what I can find is documentation on Ruby (http://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-ruby-examples/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **GoodData** offers **public APIs**, it is for sure possible to write any custom script for achieving of your objective **including Python**.

Please see GoodData API documentation on https://developer.gooddata.com/api.

The reason you can see a lot of Ruby specific documentation is, that GoodData offers in-house developed Ruby SDK.